# iterate over object and change object value

Tags: javascript

I have the following object:

```
orderSummeryPopin: {
    billingAddress: false, 
    shippingAddress: false,
    changeAddress: false
}
```

Now I would like to iterate over the object and if the key is equal to the parameter I pass to the function I would like to change the value of that particular key to "true" **while setting the others to false**.

My function would look kind of like this:

```
showPopin(selectedPopin) {
    for (var popin in this.orderSummeryPopin) {
        if (selectedPopin === popin) {
            popin = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I know that

```
popin = true
```

doesn't change anything on the object itself. So how can I achieve that?

Comment: `this.orderSummeryPopin[popin] = true;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. It'll iterate over each key/value pair in the original object, and set the value to true if the current `key` name matches `selectedPopin` and to false otherwise.

```
function showPopin(selectedPopin) {
  for(var key in orderSummeryPopin) {
        orderSummeryPopin[key] = selectedPopin === key;
    }
}
```

Comment: As an aside, the third line checks for equality and then assigns the result (true/false) as the value of the current key. This is somewhat easier to read than having an if statement and then extra logic inside.

Comment: Thanks so much, Jamie! Great solution!